# Missing return statement making triangle program

Tags: java, return

```
public String displayType(int side1, int side2,int side3)
    {
        if(( side1+side2 > side3))

            if(( side1==side2) && (side2==side3))//tell if equalateral
            {
                return ("Equalateral Triangle.");
            }
            else if (( side1==side2) & (side2 != side3) || (side1 == side3) & (side3 != side1))//tells if isosceles
            {
                return ("Isosceles Triangle.");
            }
            else if ((side1 != side2) & (side2 != side3))//tells if scalene
            {
                return ("Scalene Triangle.");        

        }
    } // missing return statement here error
```

I'm making a program that determines triangles. This is where I'm getting my error When I compile this. It gives an missing return statement at the end. How would fix this?

Comment: What if non of the conditions is `true`? You'll be missing a `return` statement.

Comment: ..what if all conditions in if-else block fails??what would it return..thats what error is all about

Comment: Anybody has noticed that the and comparative is ok only the first time ? Should be always &&, not &

Comment: I get what you guys are saying that it needs to return something if the conditions fail but what would that look like at the end? I'm learning java and I need an example please.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, What happens all of your conditions failed to execute ??

Possible solutions :

- You need to provide an else block there.When you provide a else
  block, then it is sure that always there is a chance to return the
  value, either in `if`  or in `else` .
- A default return statement without regarding `if-else`, where the
  returning value should be decide in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As the final logic (in your case) will always be true, you do not need the final `else if`

simply

```
return ("Scalene Triangle.");
```

But what will happen if the below if false?

```
if(( side1+side2 > side3))
```

You need to return something.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is saying that You have to return something,because if all your IF conditions fail then what will it do?

you can do like this:

```
public String displayType(int side1, int side2,int side3)
{
    if(( side1+side2 > side3))

        {
if(( side1==side2) && (side2==side3))//tell if equalateral
        {
            return ("Equalateral Triangle.");
        }
        else if (( side1==side2) & (side2 != side3) || (side1 == side3) & (side3 != side1))//tells if isosceles
        {
            return ("Isosceles Triangle.");
        }
        else if ((side1 != side2) & (side2 != side3))//tells if scalene
        {
            return ("Scalene Triangle.");        

    }
return ("It is not a triangle");
} // missing return statement here error
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String displayType(int side1, int side2,int side3)
{
    if(( side1+side2 > side3)){

        if(( side1==side2) && (side2==side3))//tell if equalateral
        {
            return "Equalateral Triangle.";
        }
        else if (( side1==side2) & (side2 != side3) || (side1 == side3) & (side3 != side1))//tells if isosceles
        {
            return "Isosceles Triangle.";
        }
        else if ((side1 != side2) & (side2 != side3))//tells if scalene
        {
            return "Scalene Triangle.";        

        }
                        }
  else{
     return "Not a triangle";
      }
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work. I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: @user3296193 if this edit does not work just run this code`public String displayType(int side1, int side2,int side3)
{return "Not a triangle";} ` and start adding if else one by one if you get error post that error

Comment: what would that look like exactly? i'm sorry I more of a visual learner.

Comment: @user3296193 Is the code that i gave in previous comment running or not?