# missing return statement for a for loop to sort numbers from lowest to highest

Tags: java, sorting, numbers, return

```
public int sorting ( int side1, int side2,int side3)
{ 
    int[] xx= {side1,side2,side3};
    int trace=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < xx.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < xx.length; j++) {
            if (xx[i] > xx[j]) {
                int save= xx[i];
                xx[i]= xx[j];
                xx[j]= save;
            }
            trace++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
        int number = xx[i]; 
        return number;
    }
}// missing return statement
```

Making a method that sorts numbers from lowest to highest as part for a triangle program and it giving me a missing return statement error. I don't know what I'm missing exactly. Please help.

Comment: What happens if in your last loop `i` is bigger than `xx.length`?

Comment: And you can't return multiple values from a method (which your intend to do with your for loop). Return the whole array instead.

Comment: For what the compiler knows, the last `for` loop could never be entered --> missing `return` statement

Comment: Your [previous question is pretty much the same as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823383/missing-return-statement-making-triangle-program), and there are multiple explanations people have provided for it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define one return statement after the for loops as well like in your case, because there can be the case that loop will not run, you can do like

```
public int sorting ( int side1, int side2,int side3)
        { 
            int[] xx= {side1,side2,side3};
            int trace=0,number = 0;///declare the variable so it should be accessible outside the loop


            for (int i = 0; i < xx.length-1; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < xx.length; j++) {
                    if (xx[i] > xx[j]) {
                        int save= xx[i];
                        xx[i]= xx[j];
                        xx[j]= save;
                    }
                    trace++;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
               number = xx[i]; 

            }
            return number;//return statement in the method you can also declare the return statements in the loop but method should also contain one return statement
        }
```

and if you want to return the values one by one then it is not possible so in that case best option is to create array and store the number inside it and then return that array

Comment: But the last for loop is pointless, it always be `return xx[xx.length-1]`. I think the OP is trying to return all the values in the array one by one, which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your last for loop doesn't really make sense

```
for (int i = 0; i < xx.length; i++) {
    int number = xx[i]; 
    return number;
}
```

This will always return `xx[0]`. Why have a `for` loop there at all?

The error you're getting is happening because the compiler doesn't know whether the `for` loop will be entered, so it think that it's possible for the loop to be skipped, in which case there would be no `return` statement.

Instead of your `for` loop, you probably meant

```
return xx;
```

But then you need to change the method signature to

```
public int[] sorting ( int side1, int side2,int side3)
```